# How to update table using foreign key in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a table, but my query is not correct. I don't know where I am making a mistake. Here it is:

```
UPDATE employee 
SET image = '123.jpg' 
WHERE employee.emp_id=personal_data.emp_Id;
```

Where `emp_Id` is a `primary key` in `personal_data` table and a `foreign key` in `employee` table .

Comment: Tag your DBMS. If it's MS-SQL you can join the tables like a normal `SELECT` and then change the `SELECT` to an `UPDATE` and specify the table's alias. `UPDATE a set ...`

Comment: this thread should help you ... [Update with Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: Tag the dbms used!!! You've already got a couple of product specific answers and tips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
UPDATE employee  
SET E.image = '123.jpg' 
FROM employee,personal_data
where employee.emp_id = personal_data.emp_id
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer. (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: He has SQL tagged (as language), which means ANSI SQL.

Comment: yes that what i was trying to do but i was missing FROM section @SandeepKumar

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
UPDATE E 
SET E.image = '123.jpg' 
FROM personal_data P 
INNER JOIN employee  E
    ON E.emp_id = P.emp_id
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer. (MS SQL Server?)